# is there a way to split a string in sql?

Tags: sql, sql-server-2012

i got a column with a value something like this.

```
digits
1,2,3
12,4,5
3,45,56
```

and i want to split the value in the row into individual, is there any simple way to do this in SQL ? im using vb.net. thanks in advance

Comment: which DBMS ???. > _is there any simple way to do this in SQL ?_ < **Yes** but you need to specify in which Database that you want perform this task

Comment: possible duplicate of [Tsql split string](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10914576/tsql-split-string)

Answer (score 0):

TRY THIS:

```
 SELECT GROUP_CONCAT((digits) SEPARATOR ', ') as digits FROM table
```

Comment: I am confused to your question and im trying to understand, but try my updated query if my sample query may help.